# What does the following set symbol notation mean

Tags: notation

[6] x [6] -> Z

I know it's the cartesian product of [6], but I don't quite understand what [6] means?
Does it mean all numbers until 6, or is another way to write {6}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[n]$ is a common notation for the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: This is correct.